# 1200W, voltage and cycle converter 220 to110

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, frequency, step-down, frequency-measurement

I have bought a Joule sous vide immersion circulator  from USA. I want to use the device in India. I need to convert AC, 240V 50Hz to 110V 60Hz.

After reading the literature on the company's website it seems that just converting the voltage will not help, as the equipment design is such that it won't work properly.

Is there anything available that will convert both voltage and frequency simultaneously?

The device is 1100W, so please advise what can be done to use it without blowing it up.

Comment: perhaps a UPS could work

Comment: Anything that would convert both voltage and frequency at 1100W would be far more expensive than buying an immersion circulator rated for the correct input.

Comment: Well, you could look for rotary converters and motor-generator sets for changing the frequency, if you are sure that the frequency is also a problem. That's the old fashion way. I also agree with the other two comments in that case, as well. If frequency isn't a problem, then a transformer comes to mind.

Comment: Do I need linear or SMPS

Comment: You can [edit] this question using the word "edit" right under the keyword list.   Please do not edit other people's answers.   Please do not repost the same question with minor changes, [edit] this question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an extract of the specifications accessible at

https://www.chefsteps.com/joule/specs

***Performance***

*1100 watts heating power*

***Electrical and Operating Requirements***

*Line voltage 100 to 120 V AC*

*Frequency 50 to 60 Hz, single phase*

You would need a single-phase auto-transformer with the following specifications:

Input 240 V 50 Hz

Output 110 V 15 A

Frequency is not an issue as the specified range is 50 to 60 Hz.

Comment: Such transformers are often available from builders merchants (in the UK : ask locally!) at pretty good prices, because 110V power tools are often preferred for their lower voltage in a busy dangerous environment. Bonus : they are encased in yellow plastic, and splashproof.

Comment: Yes, Brian, there must be a good market for those handy, safe and reasonably priced units in the UK.

Comment: Would linear or SMPS be better

Comment: Those are DC power supplies.  The suggested auto-transformer would be your best bet.